# PHP code for checkboxes for an HTML email form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

I am using a tutorial for an HTML/PHP email form, it does validation and what not and showcases text fields and select fields, it however does not show checkboxes.

Here is the URL to the tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/

The text field code looks like such

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['phone'] : '' ?>" placeholder="555-555-5555" />
```

The select looks like such

```
<option value="Select a size" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['size'] == 'Select a size') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Select a size</option>
```

What I am trying to figure out how to get the above to be proper syntax when using checkboxes.
Here is my attempt

```
<input type="checkbox" id="color" name="color" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['red'] : '' ?>" />
```

It is improper syntax. Mind you I am going to have multiple checkboxes and 1 or all might need to be shown in the recipient email. Can someone please assist that would be awesome.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am looking to achieve the same results that the text and select fields do as shown in the tutorial link. Being that this form works for select and text fields, I now have a client that requires checkboxes in their form.

Comment: I mean, what do you expect the ternary operation to 'do'.

Comment: Being that it seems to be a bit irrelevant for this case, and I don't fully understand what you are talking about even with the provide URL below (I am new with PHP) I am going to leave this ternary code (TRUE/False) out

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct you are trying to set the checked state. You are doing this in the `value` attribute, which is incorrect. Assuming this is the checkbox for the color `red` something like this should be the syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="color" 
       name="color" 
       value="red"
       <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['red']) 
                  ? 'checked="checked"'
                  : ''; ?> 
       />
```

An example of the ternary operation:

```
// Like asking php a question
(TRUE) ? 'this is true' : 'this is false';
--> 'this is true'
```

Broken down into a regular if/else statement:

```
if(TRUE)
{
    echo 'this is true';
}
else
{
    echo 'this is false';
}
--> 'this is true'
```

Comment: This will still get the form to work? i.e. in the tutorial it shows that the form is supposed to validate and show a green check message or a red X message see tutorial above for reference. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Amazing I don't understand what this does The ternary operation in more detail:
// Like asking php a question
(TRUE) ? 'this is true' : 'this is false';
--> 'this is true'
Broken down into a regular if/else statement:
if(TRUE)
{
    echo 'this is true';
}
else
{
    echo 'this is false';
}

Comment: It does nothing, just an example of a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) as you did not seem to fully comprehend what it is. And no, this should not influence any existing functionality.

Comment: So it doesn't need to be included?

Comment: Also if I have multiple check boxes with a name/id of color and some selects more than one option, will both options show in the recipient email?

Comment: So probably better to trick it and make each of the check box name/ids unique

Comment: like red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, pink, brown, black, white, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary operator syntax is not correct for the checkboxes:

```
($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['red'] : ''
```

You're missing the `?` part and never close the parentheses.  This will result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

These lines had problems, as well....

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] ? $cf['posted_form_data']['phone'] : '');?>" placeholder="555-555-5555" />
<option value="Select a size" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['size'] == 'Select a size' ? "selected='selected'" : '');?>>Select a size</option>
```

Comment: What would the corrections be? Note in the tutorial this is to help advise the person filling the form out that the form is either valid or invalid, will your below corrections as well as the ones for these two lines still make this work?